# Select an ID from a parent element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to access the id of the parent element. This code I am using and it's not working

```
var tag_id= $('.tag').closest('.tag').attr('id');
alert(tag_id)
```

This is my html

```
<div class='tag' id='<?php echo "$id";?>'>
   <span class='tagName' id='<?php echo "$tag_name";?>'>Something</span>
</div>
```

I am not using .click() or .hover()

Probably the html div is in a while loop so 10 records will come from the database and it shows the same id for all records

EDIT:

I have another var but I didn't include this is it:

```
var tag_name = $('.tag').children('.tagName').attr('id');
```

its the name of the tag even though it's coming same for all tags

I tried the code from the answer for the second one and it didn't work

Comment: show ur html including parent.

Comment: which element u are calling 'parent' ?, i am not getting it

Comment: @Rim show your full rendered html..

Comment: Are you want tagname ?

Comment: @Sudharsan Yes the tagname

Comment: var tag_name = $('.tag').prop('tagName');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html:

```
<div class='tag' id="<?php echo $id;?>">
   <span class='tagName' id="<?php echo $tag_name;?>">Something</span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.tag').find('.tagName').attr('id'); // get child id

$('.tag').attr('id'); // parent id
```

Comment: `var tag_name = $('.tag').prop('tagName').attr('id');` like this ? I need it's ID sorry for a lot of questions

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - then how to get the id of the class using tagname

Comment: var tag_name = $('.tag').prop('tagName').attr('id'); I wrote it like this and it didn't work. tagName is the class?

Comment: @Rim - No,TagName returns the string like SPAN, DIV like this

Comment: Use like $('.tag').find('.tagName').attr('id');

Comment: I used `$('.tag').find('span').attr('id');` I dont know why it's not working

Comment: Updated my answer please now

Comment: @Sudharsan Thanks man for stressing your self to help me really thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var tag_id= $('.tag').attr('id');
alert(tag_id)
```

Comment: +1 it seems there's no point in using `$('.tag').closest('.tag')`

Comment: Hello your answer is exactly like Dheeraj Kumar